# How to read a diff file in python, extract added lines and remove them (change to old patch)?

Tags: python, diff, patch

I have unifled diff patch like this

```
@@ -3224,10 +3221,7 @@ void THTensor_(logspace)(THTensor *r_, real a, real b, long n)
  }

  if(n == 1) {

    TH_TENSOR_APPLY(real, r_,
 -       *r__data = TH_MATH_NAME(pow)(10.0, a);
 -       i++;
 -       );
 +   THTensor_(set1d)(r_, 0, TH_MATH_NAME(pow)(10.0, a));
  } else {
    TH_TENSOR_APPLY(real, r_,
        *r__data = TH_MATH_NAME(pow)(10.0, a + i*(b-a)/((real)(n-1)));
```

How I can read it in python, extract new lines and remove them from the diff patch to generate the old patch?

Comment: It is unclear what you need. Do you want to remove the lines that begin with the plus sign (`+`)?

Comment: Yes, I need to remove the lines star with "+" from the patch and save them in a file.

Answer (score 0):

There is https://pypi.org/project/unidiff/ that can be used to read the unified diff and operate on it.

It is unclear to me what you want to achieve with modifying the diff. If you want to reverse the change from the diff, you can use `patch --reverse`.